# Matching and extracting text from label.text?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Hi I want to extract specific string from label's text. How to achieve it. I thought of one way using regex, now I know how to match to a regex but don't know how to extract.

e.g. The label text is

```
    name: tom
```

I want to extract

```
    tom
```

i.e.

```
    (:)([a-z]*)(\n)
```

How can be this achieved using visual basic 2010?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean VB.NET and not VBA, because you say "visual basic 2010".  I'll make the modification to your tags so that people who can help you will be able to find your question :)

Comment: `Hi I want to extract specific string from label's text.` Do you want to check that the string is in the text? Or remove it from the text? It's not really clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remove method of string objects.  This code would produce a messagebox that just says "Tom".

```
Dim mystring As String = "name: Tom"

MessageBox.Show(mystring.Remove(0, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want text *after* the first colon character, a simple Substring would work where you find the index of the first colon character:

```
string test = "Name: Tom";
string result = test.Substring(test.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want tom, you can try to do this:

```
dim t as string = "tom"
replace(tom, "name: ", "")
```

then your variable `t` will hold "tom"